# Is a question better with a "drive-by diss" than without it?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

I found a couple of questions that included seemingly unnecessary opinions about the movies/shows in question:

[Is Johnny in Cobra Kai a sympathetic character?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/101670/is-johnny-in-cobra-kai-a-sympathetic-character)

> As a preface to this question, I will say I only know what I see about the new Karate Kid series (Cobra Kai) from YouTube commercials; **I have no interest in devoting time to watching what looks to be a train wreck.**

[How did Baby's Dad let her down in Dirty Dancing?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23139/how-did-babys-dad-let-her-down-in-dirty-dancing)

> I just watched Dirty Dancing with my wife the other night - **great dancing, but man, pretty much a B-movie end-to-end otherwise.**

So I edited them to remove the "movie review" aspects of these questions so the text would focus on the actual question.

Both edits were rejected.

Should they have been?  Are these one-liners with one's opinion of a movie really an improvement on a question without them?

Comment: Yeah...I just approved these suggestions retroactively. Thanks for bringing this up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes, these are good edits.

For pretty much exactly the reasons you said: they're not relevant, they don't add anything to the post, and they could be construed as rude. If it's actually relevant to the post (e.g. "why did such-and-such film do badly at the box office"), then of course it's fine to include criticism of the film, provided it's expressed in a polite and constructive way. But if someone just feels the need to express their negative opinion when it's not required or relevant for the question, then they can go and do so on their blog - nothing is lost by editing that out.

Don't go hunting out such remarks for a mass-editing spree, but if you happen to see them and they bother you, then by all means get rid of them. Indeed, your edits have been retroactively approved by a site moderator, so all's well that ends well.

Related meta from a sister site: [What should we do about snarky comments denigrating specific works?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31/17) (spoiler: delete them).

Comment: Regarding comments, this [has been discussed here](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2605/49) too already (albeit a bit unluckily titled).